# Does jquery trigger slidedown animation on an element that is already slidedown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well I hope the question is self-explanatory. I have the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > sliderTop) {
        $('#slider').slideDown(1000);
    } else {
        $('#slider').slideUp(1000);
    }
});
```

If I scroll down after a certain point the slideDown function will be called continuously. does JQuery animates it over and over again or is it smart enough to know that the element is already slide down? (currently I'm using a flag to check whether its already slide down).

Answer (score 1):

The animation won't run again. See lines 459-468 in `effect.js` in the [jquery src](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/085814474e4a854d533b5ccbaef24c090081e0c4/src/effects.js)

```
doAnimation = function() {
            // Operate on a copy of prop so per-property easing won't be lost
            var anim = Animation( this, jQuery.extend( {}, prop ), optall );

            // Empty animations, or finishing resolves immediately
            if ( empty || data_priv.get( this, "finish" ) ) {
                anim.stop( true ); // ** here - stopping right after started.
            }
        };
        doAnimation.finish = doAnimation;
```

But I would still recommend against it to improve code readability. just use a boolean, it doesn't hurt...